# How to copy directories and files from a corrupted harddrive?

Tags: backup, dd, data-corruption

I have an **I/O error** every time I copy folders and files from a partition to a backup harddrive .

So how can I safely backup this data to my backup HDD?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, if your drive is experiencing I/O errors you should check if your drive is healthy enough. I/O errors might be localized only on a/some specific bad block/bad blocks, but having one/some is how a drive failure usually starts.

You can use `smartctl` to check your drive's `S.M.A.R.T.` status, which provides many informations about the drive's overall conditions, most interestingly about the reallocated / current pending sectors count. You can install `smartctl` by installing the package `smartmontools`:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install smartmontools
```

For `SATA` drives, you can check your drive's `S.M.A.R.T.` status by running:

```
sudo smartctl -a -d <device_file>
```

<sub>*<device_file> = device file to which your drive is mapped to (in the form of `/dev/sdX`; you can check this by running `lsblk`);</sub>

For `IDE` drives, you can check your drive's `S.M.A.R.T.` status by running:

```
sudo smartctl -a <device_file>
```

<sub>*<device_file> = device file to which your drive is mapped to (in the form of `/dev/sdX`; you can check this by running `lsblk`);</sub>

The most important indexes to be checked are `Reallocated sector count` and `Current pending sector count`. The former provides the number of the drive's "dead" sectors, while the latter provides the number of the drive's "almost dead" sectors which will be reallocated if a further read attempt on them fails.

If the disk is a little aged, those numbers are not likely to be 0, which is the ideal condition. How alarming those numbers actually are it depends, expecially on the drive's age and size; consider that each "dead" sector on most hard drives equals to `512 B` worth of storage space lost already, but most of all an already high number is usually prone to increase more quickly and it's usually an indicator of a close fail.

Aside from that, you can try with `ddrescue`. If the partition containing the file(s) you're trying to recover is the `root` partition, do this from a Live DVD, since the target filesystem must be mounted read-only.

**Also beware that reading/writing a non healthy drive might ruin it further.** `ddrescue` is meant to do as less damage as possible, but there are no guarantees.

First, if the target partition is mounted, unmount it:

```
sudo umount /media/<username>/<partition_mount_point>
```

<sub>*<username> = your username; <partition_mount_point> = partition's mount point (you can check this by running `lsblk`);</sub>

Remount the target partition as read-only:

```
sudo mkdir /media/<username>/ddrescue && sudo mount -o ro /dev/<sdXY> /media/<username>/ddrescue
```

<sub>*<username> = your username; <sdXY> = block device to which the partition is mapped (you can check this by running `lsblk`);</sub>

Create a directory in which to copy the recovered file(s) (in this case it's a "`recovered`" folder in your `home`):

```
mkdir ~/recovered
```

Run `ddrescue`:

```
ddrescue /media/<username>/ddrescue/<file_path> ~/recovered
```

<sub>*<username> = your username; <file_path> = file's path in the target partition;</sub>

And repeat this last step for each file you wish to recover.

Once done, unmount the target partition and remove the temporary folder:

```
sudo umount /media/<username>/ddrescue && sudo rmdir /media/<username>/ddrescue
```

<sub>*<username> = your username;</sub>

Comment: Maybe add `smartctl` to check if there are any errors?  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Yes, done :)

Comment: And upvoted!  ;-)

Comment: `sudo mkdir /media/<username>/ddrescue && sudo mount -o ro /dev/<sdXY> /media/<username>/ddrescue` does not work, it says `You must specify a filesystem type with -t`